# Updating PIP version on Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to deploy my Azure Function from VSCode, however am coming across an error whilst building a wheel.

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for Bottleneck\nERROR: Could not build wheels for Bottleneck which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Azure Functions Details:

- Python 3.7.9
- Linux Function app running on Consumption plan

I believe this is related to the version of PIP installed. How do I go about updating this?